# Does the Area 51 proposal “High Energy Physics” overlap with this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Similar to my question [Does the Area 51 proposal "Experimental or Applied Physics" duplicate this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/720/does-the-area-51-proposal-experimental-or-applied-physics-duplicate-this-site) <sub>(which could still use a consensus—hint, hint …)</sub>

---

There's an Area 51 proposal named [High Energy Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6633/high-energy-physics).

While I've looked at your FAQ, I don't know the field well enough to be comfortable making the call on my own—which brings me here.

Can y'all review that proposal, and give your opinion as to whether it overlaps with or duplicates this site or [Theoretical Physics](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I largely second [David's comments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/956/does-the-area-51-proposal-high-energy-physics-overlap-with-this-site/957#957).

Moreover, if there are a few leftover topics then they must be the sort that would also fit on the still pending [Experimental or Applied Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32588/experimental-or-applied-physics) site.

I recognize that the HEP proposal is further along, but I think that dividing into

- High level theoretical
- Nitty gritty experimental reality
- Everything else physics

is more defensible that suggesting that every significant sub-field should have it's own site. Not only does that break the Stack Overflow model (where c, perl, haskel, postscript, c#, etc get along just fine on one site) but it reduces the possibility for useful cross-fertilization of skills between the disciplines.

Frankly I'm not entirely happy with three sites, but I certainly think that it is better than HEP and solid state and optics and AMO and...

Comment: ... and newton's first law and proof that polyakov becomes nambu-goto at the classical limit? : ) +1.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for bringing this up, I'd actually wondered about it a while back... at this stage, I'm inclined to say **yes**, the High Energy Physics proposal overlaps with both this site and Theoretical Physics. Out of the top 20 non-closed example questions for the HEP proposal, 13 and a half could be asked here on Physics (and several of those could also be asked on Theoretical Physics). Several others seem like they would be good fits for [Scientific Computing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/scientific-computing-was-computational-science).

Since I'm procrastinating, here are the specifics (at least in my personal judgment of what is on- and off-topic here):

- Are there any robustly understood examples of theories that dynamically break a chiral symmetry but do not confine? (The opposite is well-known.)
  **on topic** here
- Can someone give a summary of current phenomenological constraints for neutrino mass?
  **on topic** here
- What are good references to learn about Seiberg duality and its applications to particle physics?
  **on topic** here
- How do I interface Pythia 8 with Rivet?
  **off topic** here, but probably a good fit for Scientific Computing
- How is the W boson mass measured at hadron colliders?
  **on topic** here
- How much the PDF's uncertainties affect the LHC SUSY discovery potential?
  **on topic** here
- What is a "jet energy scale correction"?
  **on topic** here
- How does one calculate the baryon- and lepton-number violation coming from instanton effects?
  **on topic** here
- What are the differences between analytical resummation and parton shower approximation?
  **on topic** here
- What is a sufficiently general ansatz for \Gamma_k in the exact renormalization flow equation of the standard model?
  **on topic** here
- Is there a CAS which supports anticommuting variables like spinors or Grassmann variables?
  **off topic** here, *possibly* on topic at Super User
- What LHC luminosity is needed to confirm/refute the standard model Higgs?
  **on topic** here
- Are there any other first-principles calculations for QCD other than lattice QCD? For lattice QCD, are there any algorithms better than Metropolis?
  part 1 **on topic** here, part 2 **off topic** (well, borderline) but appropriate for Scientific Computing
- What are the "Van der Meer scans" used to get collider luminosity normalisation?
  **on topic** here
- Can I run MC@NLO events through Herwig++?
  probably **off topic** here but appropriate for Scientific Computing
- How do I configure madevent/madgraph to simulate color octet scalars?
  probably **off topic** here but appropriate for Scientific Computing
- How do underlying event, pile up and initial state radiation differ, both in their conception and their observable effects?
  **on topic** here
- How do I implement finite collinear terms from the dipole subtraction?
  probably **off topic** here but appropriate for Scientific Computing or Stack Overflow (depends on what exactly the question asks)
- How can I build CERNLIB on [a modern machine]?
  **off topic** here but probably appropriate for either Scientific Computing or Super User, depending on the specifics
- Have any plausible direct experimental searches for a QCD axion with ~GUT-scale decay constant been proposed?
  **on topic** here

Comment: "Is there a CAS which supports anticommuting variables like spinors or Grassmann variables?" This will hardly be a fit. The subtitle of the proposal mentions "heavy computing", the example questions bear that out.