# Experimental technology questions: on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

So far the scope of Physics Stack Exchange has been defined to exclude experimental technology questions, which are those questions about the devices that one uses to do physics, rather than about the physical principles they use. Some of these questions fit on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), and there was a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32588/experimental-or-applied-physics) that would have been a great home for these questions. However, that proposal is no more, and given that this site is well established with a steady flow of physical principles questions, **is it time that we start to allow the questions about experimental technology?**

Here is a recent example that prompted this question: 
[Strategies against 50 Hz mains hum on detector signals?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22552/good-electronic-filters-against-50hz-mains-hum)

See also [Does the Area 51 proposal "Experimental or Applied Physics" duplicate this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/720/does-the-area-51-proposal-experimental-or-applied-physics-duplicate-this-site)

Comment: "is it time that we start to allow the questions about experimental technology?" Yes.Absolutely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mains hum one was a relatively simple EE problem, which was simple enough to stay on the scope of physics (AC rejector circuits seem pretty OK to me). But yes, it would have found a better home on EE.SE.

I would say that these should stay on topic. Multiple reasons:

- This is the best place for them. (Experimental) physicists here will be familiar with experimental tech, and can provide detailed answers.
- Experimental physics is a large part of Physics. Experimental tech does not focus on any concept, but neither does experimental physics. We can not afford to ignore experimental physics/tech on a *physics* site.
- The general question of feasibility of a setup is a great one, and experimental tech is a large part of feasibility.

Update: I have created  [experimental-technology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-technology) to hold such questions.

Comment: One of my own experimental tech questions: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/accuracy-of-various-optical-instruments

Comment: I second Manishearth's reasons for keeping experimental-technology questions in sight of the physicists frequenting physics.stackexchange

Comment: I suggest the tag 'experimental technique' instead of 'experimental technology'.

Comment: @nibot [tag:experimental-technique] exists, but I'm not sure it has enough overlap.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @nibot technique has to do with setup and how to formulate an experiment taking real-world issues into consideration. Experimental technology has to do with the tech involved in physics.. The accuracy etc. Currently, experimental technique is allowed, technology isn't.

Comment: Here's another example question, one of mine: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94/what-ways-are-there-to-measure-the-local-polarization-of-a-laser-beam

Comment: @ptomato imo that's more experimental technique. Not experimental technology.

Comment: I felt it was more like "what technology is available to solve this problem" although it is probably a little of both.

Comment: @ptomato well, it really depends upon your intentions. To me, it didn't look like you wanted technology advice--it looked more like you wanted help in formulating a setup. If it was the former, yes, it falls under both I guess.

Comment: FWIW I wasn't being very precise with my usage of "experimental technology" in the question - I just meant questions which are about devices or procedures used to do physics and not about the physics concepts themselves. So perhaps both experimental-technique and experimental-technology would be appropriate, and likely more (since this proposal potentially doubles the scope of the site, I wouldn't expect all the new stuff to fit under one or two tags)

Comment: I just tried to use the experimental-technology tag and my question was tagged off-topic with votes to close. I think this is quite bad. This site's attitude that experiment doesn't count is really terrible and I would like to know what I can do to help fight for these questions to be accepted here. Here's the question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135259/how-can-i-make-a-dry-dilution-refrigerator-quiet

Comment: @DanielSank that deserves a separate meta post.

Comment: @Manishearth: Any suggestions on how to frame this so folks don't get offended? I am apparently not so good at this.

Comment: @DanielSank Don't directly make general assumptions about the site's attitude/etc in the question, you ought to be fine. Approach it as something which we probably should discuss/incorporate into the engineering policy, without any presumptions :)

Comment: @Manishearth: Thanks. And... for what it's worth, I think the idea that the site isn't friendly toward experiment isn't so much an assumption as an observation.

Comment: @DanielSank An observation from how large a sample space? We even have one mod who is an experimental physicist, and he has helped keep it alive. Not to say that the community isn't biased when it comes to this, but it isn't really an absolute bad attitude IMO. This particular closing might be due to the policy having issues (which says nothing about the community, just the policy) -- the policy wasn't made to put down experimental qs, just to put down a particular type of question that was really unwanted. It's a bit broader than it should be, maybe.

Comment: (Anyway, it's such assumptions in the question that will just serve to annoy everyone and you won't get a constructive response :p)

Comment: @Manishearth: Your words are well taken.