# Would this question be allowed to migrate to Physics.Main?

Tags: discussion

Would this question be allowed to migrate to Physics.Main?

[What are the specs of the components I would need to make a 1050 kph, non-rocket-propelled motorbike?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/what-are-the-specs-of-the-components-i-would-need-to-make-a-1050-kph-non-rocket)

If I'm allowed to migrate, would/could I get answers like this? Keeping in mind that this is the kind of answer that I want...:

> Assuming a flat, asphalt road, and a rider that weighs X kg/lb/[Whatever], to get your motorcycle moving, your wheels need T torque, which means your engine needs to output E [Energy or CCs or whatever...].
>
> And that's assuming that everything is 100% efficient. If it's not, then your engine needs more power, and that power is dependent on the efficiency of engine to wheel torque, Z. The equation for the power needed for an inefficient engine, is E/Z.
>
> And *that's* assuming that your chassis is weightless. If your chassis has weight W, [explain equation for motor energy for that scenario...]
>
> Then the material of your wheel has to do this and that... [Stuff]...
>
> Finally, the material of your chassis has to do [Stuff] to handle moving at 1050 mph...

---

**Can anyone spoiler the following?** Like with this: [Achille Hui's spoiler](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/hierarchical-spoilers/13738#13738)

... Okay... this seems really silly now... 'Cause the initial idea for this question was to figure out:

> "If such a motorcycle is possible, what has to change about physics?"

Which led to this chain of questions:

> 1. What the requirements for those motorcycle parts?
> 2. Are any of those requirements achievable by real-world physics, and for the parts that aren't, what bits of physics would need to change?
> 3. What would the implications of those physics changes be on the capabilities of technology?
>
> 3.5. How do I have humans live in a world with those physics?

Those last two questions seem to be reasonable worldbuilding questions, if the changes weren't too broad...

But, in combination, that's a big jumble of theoretical physics and worldbuilding... And even the initial questions seem a bit much for a SE site... *One facepalm is not enough...*

Comment: Have you thought about [mechanics.se]? I don't know if such a question would be on topic there, but the question as phrased (or answer desired) doesn't really seem to be a physics question to me.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Well, according to their Tour page, their scope is "'Specific issues with motor vehicle maintenance or repair' and 'Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered'"  ... So, how to make a motorcycle doesn't seem to fit... Perhaps if I rework it, and repost on Engineering, that might work...

Comment: Understood, I'm not terribly aware of what a lot of the SE sites are about. Also, MathJax is not enabled on Meta.Physics, so we cannot have the Latex spoilers as Achille Hui demonstrated, though on the main site we could have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short version:** No.

That question would fall firmly under [our policy on engineering question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/520). You're not concerned with anything fundamental about how parts work or with [building an experimental apparatus](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2948/520), so while many physicist would find the question fascinating, it is not a *physics question*.