# How is this question "about engineering"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen

Why was this question

[Why is the ground warm during winter and vice-versa?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/727063/)

deemed to be "about engineering" and closed, when the OP clearly stated he was *not* asking about how to employ the difference in temperature between surface and ground at a depth  but instead **why** there is a difference in temperature?

> *"My question is not why we feel it warm, but why is it warm?"*

From the meta post linked in the motivation to close it:

> *"Physics is a natural science. It seeks to study how and/or why nature works the way we observe. Engineering applies our understanding
> of nature to specific, real-world problems, creating new devices,
> products, or processes to solve those problems."*

Is this not a question on **why** nature works the way we observe (why the ground layers are not at the same temperature of the surface) and **not on how** to employ this difference to solve the problem of heating/cooling?

It seems to me this question was closed because some answer focused more on the application of the physics than on the physics itself. But isn't the question about the underlying physics?
The book I cited in my answer is "Partial Differential Equations *in Physics*", not "in engineering". I was entertaining the thought of expanding my answer with the reasoning employed by Sommerfeld, but not anymore.

As an aside: closing this question prevents further answers to the physics question to be added, for example on how much of the heat is due to the surface heating from the sun, and how much comes from the hot core inside. What will the average temperature at 10 or 100 meters be if we switch off the sun, or if we remove the hot core?

Comment: FWIW, the [close review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/391404) had 2 Leave Open votes, so this was not an unanimous decision.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that happens when you reduce the number of votes required to close a question.  It would be instructive to look at the fraction of closed questions that were subsequently re-opened, and see how that number has changed since the change from a 5-vote to a 3-vote close.  It definitely feels to me like this number has gone up, but I don't know whether it's gotten high enough to be of concern to the community.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert on the other hand the review queues are now manageable.  (I don’t have an issue with reopening questions.)

Comment: If only there were some intermediate position between 3 and 5...

Comment: Physicist see house, physicist think engineering. Basically people voted to close without carefully reading and thinking about what was asked.

Comment: I made my case on this issue [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6135). Your question should not have been closed. I am sorry on behalf of the usership that it was closed. Let's get it re-opened.