# Fabrication Discussion - Is Physics the place for it?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

While Fabrication (usually referring to MEMS/NEMS<sup>1</sup> technology) is a fundamental part of physics, somehow I feel the physics stack isn't the place for it. The physics stack seems most suitable for discussions pertaining to theoretical and experimental results, and posting a question about fabrication techniques seems slightly out of place to me.

What do you think? Is the physics stack a good place for discussing how to fabricate MEMS/NEMS devices or should this be placed in engineering?

---

<sup>1</sup> MEMS = Micro-ElectroMechanical System and NEMS  = Nano-ElectroMechanical System.

Answer (score 7):

As with any other equipment-related questions they could be on- or off-topic.

## Probably on-topic if:

- The question related to the underlying physics of how they work
- The question related to their direct application as experimental equipment.
- The question related to the construction, characterization, calibration and tuning of one-of-a-kind experimental versions.
- Other cases where a solution is unlikely to come from anyone other than a physicist.

## Probably off-topic if:

- The question pertains to engineering of these system in general.
- The question is related to COTS units applied outside of an experimental setting.
- The question concerns hypothetical impacts on society.
- Lots of other cases where there is no obvious reason that a physicist should be involved

## References (most recent first order):

- [Experimental Physics & Engineering](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6135/520)
- [What is engineering and what is experimental design?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5553/520)
- [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/520) Note: [faq](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).
- [Should “How do I solve this experimental problem?” questions be on-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2948/520)
- [Experimental technology questions: on topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1132/520)

Comment: I would add the general rule of thumb that questions about physics are on topic, but questions about the tools used to do physics are not (necessarily).